# Woocommerce add product summary to shortcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So i have a short code im making that has the product id being passed into it.

I'm trying to display the product summary (so where the variations and purchase button is don't the right inside the product)

I've tried using using `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' ); ?>` which returned an error

any ideas would be great!

Sam

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ It might be helpful to add the error you received inside another code block within your post.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$product->get_id(); // if necessary
$product->get_short_description();
```

More about that [here](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/).

Comment: that returned nothing, Dont think this is the answer as variations wouldn't come back with this would it?